# Asymptotic analysis of generating functions

Tags: co.combinatorics, cv.complex-variables

Let $a_d\!\in\!{\mathbb R}^+$ with $d\!\in\!{\mathbb Z^+}$ be a sequence such that
$$\limsup \sqrt[d]{a_d}=1\,.$$
Define
$$F(z)=\sum_{d=1}^{\infty}a_d\,{\text{e}}^{d z}\,.$$
Suppose $F(z)$ admits an expansion around $z\!=\!0$ of the form
$$F(z)=c_0+c_1z+c_2z^2+c_{5/2} z^{5/2}+\sum_{d=6}^{\infty}c_{d/2}z^{d/2}$$
with $c_{5/2}\!\neq\!0$. Does this imply that
$$\limsup d^{7/2}a_d\in{\mathbb R}^+\quad\hbox{?}$$
${}$\

The relevant function $F$ is actually a solution of 
$$\big(9\!+\!2F'\!-\!3F''\big)F'''\!=\!2F\!-\!11F'\!+\!18F''+(F'')^2\,.$$
There is a claim in a 20-year old paper that the above $\limsup$ statement holds for $\lim$. While the ODE is (correctly) cited as the reason for the existence of the expansion around $z\!=\!0$, at least the $\lim$ conclusion must depend on it as well, but this is not explained.

I would think the first part of my question is well-known in the appropriate field. I have tried looking through the Analytic Combinatorics book mentioned in several posts here and saw statements in similar spirit, but generally not with logarithmic expansions.

Comment: Can you give a reference to the "20-year old paper"?

Comment: A popular source for "asymptotic analysis of generating functions" is Chapter 5 of *generatingfunctionology* by Herbert Wilf.  See a theorem of Darboux, Theorem 5.3.1 there.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar. Thank you for the suggestion; it looks like a nice book. Unfortunately, none of the three cases of Chapter 5 covers polylogarithmic singularities. Thm 5.3.1 is about algebraic singularities. On the other hand, looking at this book suggested to me how to think about the first part of my question and to realize that the answer to it is no. There could be a subsequence of $a_d$ with values of say $d^{-3}$. This would mean the limsup is infinite, but the expansion could be valid (if these value appear rarely enough). So, even the weaker conclusion requires some clever use of the ODE.

Comment: @JayPantone. The paper is hep-th/9412175. My $F$ is (2.54) after normalizing by $a^d$, with $a$ as in (2.59). The expansion is (2.56), along with (2.58). The limsup statement is a weaker version of (2.59). The ODE is (2.55). I'll post a note on arXiv on this with related observations and speculations from 3 years ago soon, now that I know that even the limsup conclusion is not a triviality. One of the speculations is my next MO posting.